# If you heat a closed tube, does its mass change?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass-energy

This is a result of a debate with friends. We were more concerned with the nano- and smaller-scale effects than the larger effects.

Let's assume that we have a closed tube filled with air. We weigh it and heat it simultaneously. Will it weigh less while it gets heated?

Comment: What do you think will happen? What is your reasoning so far?

Comment: Is there any particular effect you're looking for? It will weigh slightly more because of the energy applied, but you have to add roughly 90 billion joules of energy to increase the mass by one gram. You'll probably have other effects that will be much more significant, like some of the air escaping when you pressurize it, or raising the temperature in the environment lowering the air pressure there and decreasing the buoyant force so it looks like it weighs more even though it doesn't, etc.

Comment: I personally, assumed that center of gravity would rise when the air is heated, which could be observed as lowering the weight.

Answer (score 1):

It will weigh more as long as nothing boils off the surface. Why? Because $E = mc^2$. The heat energy applied adds an extremely small amount of mass (waaaaay smaller than you could measure with the equipment available to you).